# Arnold ODE §1.6 Problem 1 - explanation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** At what altitude is the density of the air one-half of that at the surface of the earth? Regard the temperature as constant. One cubic meter of air at the surface of the earth weighs $1250g$.

The solution says $8 \ln 2 \textrm{km} \approx 5.6 \textrm{km}$. I presume it comes from the half-life formula $T = -1/k \ln 2$ for DE's of type
$x' = k x$. How did he get $-1/k = 8$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For those who voting to close the problem is verbatim taken from the well known ODE textbook by Arnold. There is no other information to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Pressure varies with altitude according to the differential equation
$$
\frac{dp}{dx}=-\rho(x)g, \tag{1}
$$ where $\rho(x)$ is the density of air at altitude $x$ and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity. On the other hand, if the temperature is constant, the density of an ideal gas is proportional to pressure,
$$
\rho = \alpha p. \tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dx}=-\alpha g\rho \implies \rho(x)=\rho_0e^{-\alpha gx}. \tag{3}
$$
The altitude $h$ at which the density of air is one-half of that at the surface of the Earth is, therefore,
$$
h=\frac{\ln 2}{\alpha g}. \tag{4}
$$
To obtain the numerical value of $h$, we use Eq. $(2)$. At the surface of the Earth, the atmospheric pressure is approximately$^{(*)}$ $1.01\times 10^5$ and the density of air is $1.25$, so $\alpha\approx 1.24\times 10^{-5}$. Since $g\approx 9.81$, we finally obtain
$$
h\approx 5.7\times 10^3\,\text{m}=5.7\,\text{km}. \tag{5}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ All physical quantities are expressed in [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) units.

Comment: Thanks! I guess information external to the book was needed. Still confused as to how the book gets exactly 8 ln 2 km.

Comment: What's surprising is that Arnold provides the value of $1.25 kg/m^3$ for density, but assumes? that you know atm pressure is $1 \times 10^5 N/m^2$ for atm pressure.  Is there any way to derive that?